# How do I simulate multiple users in a remix unit test?

Tags: solidity, remix, unittesting, remix-tests

In the following example, I want to test the `assignVoter` functionality with Remix unit test plugin. `assignVoter` should only be called by the owner.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

contract Ballot {
    address owner;
    
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;    
    }
    
    function assignVoter(address voter) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
    }
}
```

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;
import "remix_tests.sol";
import "remix_accounts.sol";
import "../Ballot.sol";

contract BallotTest {
    Ballot private ballot;

    /// #sender: account-0
    function beforeAll() public {
        ballot = new Ballot();
    }

    /// #sender: account-1
    function testAssignVoter() public payable {
        ballot.assignVoter(TestsAccounts.getAccount(1));
    }
}
```

Remix provides the functionality of [custom](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unittesting.html#customization) `msg.sender` of transaction using devdoc ([NatSpec](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/natspec-format.html)). In this example, such an annotation makes the unit testing framework call the `testAssignVoter` method with 0-th test account. In turn, the creation of the `Ballot` contract and the call to `assignVoter` --- both are made by the `BallotTest` contract; neither by `account-0` or `account-1`. Therefore, I am not being able to simulate the situation where the `Ballot` contract is created by one account (`account-0`), and the `assignVoter` is called by another (`account-1`). Specifically, I want to simulate the failure scenario by hitting the `require` predicate. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I updated the code snippet, the previous one was not compilable. The test passes.

Answer (score 2):

To resemble multiple user functionality, you have to update your test file a bit with inheritance like:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;
import "remix_tests.sol";
import "remix_accounts.sol";
import "../Ballot.sol";

contract BallotTest is Ballot {

    /// #sender: account-1
    function testAssignVoter() public payable {
       assignVoter(TestsAccounts.getAccount(1));
    }
}
```

This way your test will fail as `account-1` is not owner. You can test same with a passing test case using `try-catch`. Although it is for external method call, you can use `this` to call method from same contract (Don't do that apart from a test contract).
First add error message in `require` like: `require(msg.sender == owner, 'not an owner');`

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;
import "remix_tests.sol";
import "remix_accounts.sol";
import "../Ballot.sol";

contract BallotTest is Ballot {

    /// #sender: account-1
    function testAssignVoterFailureUsingTryCatch() public {
        try this.assignVoter(TestsAccounts.getAccount(1)){
            Assert.ok(false, 'method execution should fail');
        } catch Error(string memory reason) {
            // Compare failure reason, check if it is as expected
            Assert.equal(reason, 'not an owner', 'failed with unexpected reason');
        } catch (bytes memory /*lowLevelData*/) {
            Assert.ok(false, 'failed unexpected');
        }
    }
}
```

This can help to test multiple `require` method failure from a single method.

For more test examples: https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unittesting_examples.html

Comment: When you use ```this``` doesn't the ```assignVoter``` function gets called with ```msg.sender``` set to contract address than address of ```account-1```?

Comment: No, it is updated in the transaction.

Comment: @Aniket I tried this and the ```assignVoter``` function gets called as from the contract address (this), not ```account-1```